# Why doesn't a ruleset for multiple ::selection selectors work?

Tags: css

Why is it not possible to use the same ruleset for multiple `::selection`s as it is for other elements (eg `div, span { }`) ?

Why doesn't the second example work?

This works:

```css
::selection {
 background: red; 
}
::-moz-selection {
 background: red; 
}
```

```html
some text
```

Whereas this doesn't:

```css
::selection,
::-moz-selection {
 background: red; 
}
```

```html
some text
```

Why so?

Comment: Try the snippet, it works there (on the first example).